# Able to review edit history, but certain edits invisible

Tags: support, comments, comment-edits

Why are untraceable edits allowed on content?

Initially users can see that a question of theirs has been edited, and by who, and can later get access to an edit history to see what and when the edits were made.

I have had one of my comments edited by someone with no tracing/history of the edit taking place. I have visibility into the change history of questions, answers and comments, yet this alteration does not show up. This complete lack of transparency that the comment had been edited, and by who leaves a complete lack of faith in the transparency and reliability of information on the site if some users can make untraceable ghost edits to what I write.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comments can only be edited by moderators and by the user who posted it (but then only within the initial 5-minute editing window).

If a comment is edited, either by the original poster or by a moderator, an "edited" icon (in the shape of a pencil) is shown next to the comment.

Moderators can view the revision history of comments by clicking the pencil icon, but this information is not available to anyone else.

Given all these factors, moderators generally do not edit comments. We will only do so when our only other option is to *delete* the entire comment. In that case, we may edit out an expletive or inappropriate leading/closing sentence in order to preserve the value offered by the rest of the comment.

I went to go dig it up, and what I speculated is precisely what happened in your case. You had left the following comment:

> So please contribute to SO with answers and constructive comments. It needs those, not trolls.

Calling someone a "troll" is a violation of our [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). Your comment was caught on that basis and flagged. When a moderator reviewed it, they decided that the only problematic portion of the comment was that final sentence, so they edited it and removed only that sentence, leaving the rest of the comment intact.

I don't know about you, but I strongly prefer this option over the alternative, which is to delete the entire comment. We'll still delete the whole thing if there's nothing of value or editing it is too invasive, but I have a strong preference for preserving value whenever possible.

---

As you said, aside from comments, the edit history for *everything* else on this site is publicly available, including questions, answers, tags, election nominations, …

Comment: Thanks, yes I can see the grayed pencil icon is visible for that comment showing one edit.  I had been looking at the overall edit history against my answer where the comment was recorded expecting to see something like "comment edited".